# DownloaderClientMarshaller.Proxy override superclass functions

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In the google generated code, that comes with the `google play APK expansion` i get the following error: 
[image: problem]

I didn't touch the code, so I don't think it's my bad. can any one help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project in Eclipse is probably configured to use Java 1.5 , but the generated classes are using the `@Override` annotation for interface methods. In Java 1.5 `@Override` can only be applied to methods overriding a superclass method, not methods implemented from an interface.

Open the project properties and set the java compiler level to 1.6 and make sure on the Build Path > Libraries tab a Java 1.6 library is selected.